# I wanna code a program that sums ages continuously

Tags: c++

As the title states, I need to write a program that sums ages without asking the user to enter a specific number of ages to add beforehand. User shall just keep entering the desired ages until he writes "OK". Then, the program will stop and give the result. I've tried creating a string and when the string is equal to "OK" the program stops. However, I cannot figure it out.

```
int x,age;
int total=0;
int nofpeople=0;
int average=0;

string check;

cout<<"Enter the ages and when you're done write 'OK'." << endl;

while(check!="OK")
{
    cin>>x;
    if(x>0)
    {
        age=x;
        nofpeople++;
        total=total+age;
        average=total/nofpeople;
    }
    else
    {
        check="OK";
    }
}
cout<<"Number of people you have entered=" << nofpeople << endl;
cout<<"Sum of ages=" << total<< endl;
cout<<"Average of ages=" <<average;
return 0;
```

I have a code like this but this code obviously give result for the cases that I input to x "OK" or some randow letters like"adsfasd".I want it to work specificly for "OK".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  How we do questions like this is you show us what you have and then the community help you fix it

Comment: You read input into a `std::string` variable in a loop, inside the loop you test the string for `"OK"` and if it's not "OK", you try to extract the number from the string. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Welcome ! What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Sorry, but your wording is ambiguous.  Obviously, we have a lot of beginners here and most of us are eager to help. But you are right in that we expect some concrete starting point..

Comment: Nice job reworking the question and adding code. +1. You should be able to get a decent answer now.

Comment: Instead of just doing `cin >> x`, I think you should read the input into a string, check it against "OK" and then convert to a number and store in `x`.

Comment: @NathanMills How to convert it to a number?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work, I used `istringstream` class to convert the ages into integers, with error checking in case it doesn't work.

```
int x,age;
int total=0;
int nofpeople=0;
int average=0;

string check;

cout<<"Enter the ages and when you're done write 'OK'." << endl;

while(check!="OK")
{
    string temp;
    cin>>temp;
    istringstream iss(temp);
    iss >> x;
    if(x>0)
    {
        age=x;
        nofpeople++;
        total=total+age;
        average=total/nofpeople;
    }
    else if (temp.compare("OK") == 0)
    {
        check="OK";
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Invalid or negative number entered" << endl;
    } 
}
cout<<"Number of people you have entered=" << nofpeople << endl;
cout<<"Sum of ages=" << total<< endl;
cout<<"Average of ages=" <<average;
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now, I don't understand some parts of the code but I will learn more, then it will make sense.